# firebase flutter - Receive null till reload emulator works fine

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Is there anyway to avoid Streambuilder or Futurebuilder for query data from firebase. I have tried to use Future async but error said received null till I reload the emulator after that it works fine.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class infoStudentCard extends StatefulWidget {
  
  infoStudentCard();

  @override
  _infoStudentCardState createState() => _infoStudentCardState();
}

class _infoStudentCardState extends State<infoStudentCard> {

 String userId = (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser).uid;
  String _sname;
  String _slastname;
  String _semail;
  String _sid;
  String _sclass;
  Future data;

  @override
 void initState() { 
   super.initState();
   data = getDataFromDb();
 }

 Future<void> getDataFromDb() async{
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("student")
              .doc(userId)
              .get()
              .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)  {
                    this._sname = documentSnapshot.get('sname');
 
              });
 }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_sname);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`received null till I reload the emulator after that it works fine.`

Everytime you change something, call `setState` to see the result:

```dart
 Future<void> getDataFromDb() async{
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("student")
              .doc(userId)
              .get()
              .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)  {
                 setState(() {
                   this._sname = documentSnapshot.get('sname');
                 });
              });
 }
```

Other, inside the initState, you are calling `data = getDataFromDb` but, your function return nothing. Just add:

```dart
 @override
 void initState() { 
   super.initState();
   getDataFromDb();
 }
```

or add a value to your `data` returning a value from function

```dart
 late Future<DocumentSnapshot> data;

 @override
 void initState() { 
   super.initState();
   data = getDataFromDb();
 }

Future<DocumentSnapshot > getDataFromDb() async{
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("student")
              .doc(userId)
              .get()
              .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)  {
                 setState(() {
                   this._sname = documentSnapshot.get('sname');
                 });
              });
 }
```

Comment: thanks Lucas. I got few more question, can we check documentSnapshot connection state?